# Data from the list is not displayed at the initial load

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create an App which will have a list of items on its homepage.

I already have some predefined data to display; it's hardcoded in App.js. Here's the structure (you should focus mostly on the render() method):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Details from './components/Details';
import NewItem from './components/NewItem';
import List from './components/List';

const item0 = {
  id: 0,
  img_url: "https://static.adweek.com/adweek.com-prod/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Screen-Shot-2018-10-17-at-1.25.22-PM.png",
  name: "Burger0",
  price: "10.60$",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sed accumsan neque. Donec at nunc congue, iaculis justo vel, iaculis est. Vestibulum sit amet mauris a erat pulvinar dignissim. Duis finibus consequat fermentum. Pellentesque vulputate metus quis erat cursus, at consectetur libero euismod. Proin convallis maximus mi, ac sollicitudin velit."
}

const item1 = {
  id: 1,
  img_url: "https://static.adweek.com/adweek.com-prod/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Screen-Shot-2018-10-17-at-1.25.22-PM.png",
  name: "Burger1",
  price: "10.60$",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sed accumsan neque. Donec at nunc congue, iaculis justo vel, iaculis est. Vestibulum sit amet mauris a erat pulvinar dignissim. Duis finibus consequat fermentum. Pellentesque vulputate metus quis erat cursus, at consectetur libero euismod. Proin convallis maximus mi, ac sollicitudin velit."
}

const item2 = {
  id: 2,
  img_url: "https://static.adweek.com/adweek.com-prod/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Screen-Shot-2018-10-17-at-1.25.22-PM.png",
  name: "Burger2",
  price: "10.60$",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sed accumsan neque. Donec at nunc congue, iaculis justo vel, iaculis est. Vestibulum sit amet mauris a erat pulvinar dignissim. Duis finibus consequat fermentum. Pellentesque vulputate metus quis erat cursus, at consectetur libero euismod. Proin convallis maximus mi, ac sollicitudin velit."
}

const items = [item0, item1, item2];

class App extends Component {
  addItemToList = item => {
    items.push(item);
  }

  toogleMenu = () => {
    let x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
      x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  render() {
    const toList = {
      pathname: "/",
      items: items
    }
    const toNewItem = {
      pathname: "/newitem/",
      addItemToList: this.addItemToList,
      listSize: items.length
    }

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
        <div className="topnav">
          <a href="#home" className="active">Logo</a>
          <div id="myLinks">
            <Link to={toList}>List</Link>
            <Link to={toNewItem}>New Item</Link>
          </div>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" className="icon" onClick={this.toogleMenu}>
            <i className="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/newitem/" component={NewItem} />
            <Route path="/details/" component={Details} />
            <Route path="/" component={List} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

However, the data from the List is not displayed on the initial load - I can only see the top navigation bar, and empty space below. How can the data be visible on the load, and also, how can the data be visible any time I go to pathname "/"?

After the load, I have to open the menu, click on the "List", and then the data is displayed normally. How can I implement that this situation happens by default?

**Update:**

Implementation of the List:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class List extends Component {    
    populateList = () => {
        return this.props.location.items.map((el, i) => {
            return (
            <ListItem key={i} item={el} />
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.location.items === undefined) {
            return <ul className="list"></ul>
        }
        return(
            <ul className="list">
                {this.populateList()}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

Data to load is in App.js because I also have an option to add new item, and I couldn't find another way to update items list. It would be perfect if data could be placed in List.js, and after adding new item updating List.js's state.

Comment: You need to show how the `List` is implemented. It seems like the `List ` is getting the items from the url from the look of the line ` <Link to={toList}>List</Link>`

Comment: @AnthonyKong I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `List` in your question receives `items` data via the `location` prop. When you first load your app, you app's url is likely to be `https://my.app.com/` (the root), so there is no items data for the `List` to display.

I would solve this way:

1) Modify `List` such that it can receive `items` independent of the path, e.g.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class List extends Component {    
    let items = [];
    populateList = () => {
        if (this.props.items) {
            this.items = this.props.items;
        } else { // No items via prop
           this.props.location.items.map((el, i) => {
            this.items.push(el)
           });
         }
    }

    render() {
        this.populateList()
        if (!this.items) {
            return <ul className="list"></ul>
        }
        return(
            <ul className="list">
                {this.items.map((el, i) =>
                  <ListItem key={i} item={el} />
                 }
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

2) Modify the '/' route to

```
        <Route path="/" render={() => <List items={items}/>} />
```

The code above are just for illustration and untested.